# Какие создать папки для изображений 21:9, 18:9 в Андроид приложении?

Tags: android

Какие создать папки для изображений форматов 18:9, 21:9, а то в проекте папки drawable-hdpi - drawable-xxxhdpi они скорее для изображений 16:9, а сейчас новые смартфоны в последнее время делают в основном удлиненные 21:9.

Смотрю некоторые не поняли вопроса проголосовав закрыть вопрос, объясняю. Если в папку drawable-xxxhdpi положить картинку 1920*1080 то на смартфоне 21:9 картинка будет либо растянута по вертикали либо будут рамки фона снизу и сверху, а мне нужно полное заполенние экрана картинкой без искажений

Comment: Квалификаторы ресурсов есть практически на любой случай ([см. таблицу 2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources?hl=ru#AlternativeResources)). Но вам придётся напихать в APK копий картинки для каждой пропорции * все варианты DPI * (портрет, ландшафт) - от этого он растолстеет так, что не влезет ни в один аппарат))). Вообще на бекграунд ставить художественную графику не очень хорошо (и по той же причине и по потреблению памяти в рантайме). Лучше и проще обходиться примитивами (заливка сплошным цветом, градиентом, полоски, кружки и т.п.).

Comment: Если всё же хочется картинку, то лучше сделать её одну так, чтобы значимое изображение было в центре и настроить масштабирование так чтобы менее значимые края выходили за борт.

Comment: Можно добавить только оригинал и программно создавать фон для конкретного устройства.

Answer (score 0):

Правой кнопкой по папке res, New, Android Resource Directory. В окне в левой части видим список всех возможных критериев для разделения ресурсов, там есть Ratio, это то что вам нужно.

как правильно заметили в комментариях, вам нужно 100% использовать 5 папок под различные плотности пикселей, и если вы добавляете соотношения экранов, то помножаем это количество на число разных ратио. Итого 20-30 вариантов каждого изображения. Apk будет раздуваться стремительно. Если все же решитесь делать так - заливать на плеймаркет исключительно в виде bundl-а, тогда на устройство придут только соответсвующие ему картинки, а не все сразу

Comment: я хочу только одну картинку под фон. Сейчас у меня 5 версий картинки - размер апк 4Мб и если я добавлю ещё 2 картинки под 18:9 и 21:9 - то размер апк сильно не увеличится. Думаю 10 Мб для приложения это не много на сегодняшний день

Comment: в целом да. Но камни все еще попадаются под этой водой. Например, ваш фон не будет корректно работать в режиме разделенного экрана. Либо обрежется, либо сплюснется, в зависимости от того как вы его наятгиваете на бэкграунд. Так что если вы хотите так избежать возни с расположением элементов в нужных местах - лучше не стоит. А если это просто фон - то обрезание по краям незначительное хуже не сделает, и возня с разными ратио напрасна

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы лишнее обрезалось? я делаю так

Drawable draw = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.picture, null);
RelativeLayout relativeLayout.setBackground(draw);

но у меня картинка полностью вписывается в экран

Comment: У ImageView есть атрибут scaletype, он должен вам помочь